# How to Scrape one of the span inside another span class?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

```
<span class="sim-posted">
        
            <span class="jobs-status covid-icon clearfix">
                <i class="covid-home-icon"></i>Work from Home 
            </span>
            <span>Posted few days ago</span>
            
    </span>
```

I want to scrape last span tag with text "Posted few days ago"
I have the code but its only scraping the first span with class

```
date_published=job.find('span',class_='sim-posted').span.text
```

Comment: what's the job object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is always last `<span>` you can go with `css selector` `last-of-type`:

```
soup.select_one('span.sim-posted span:last-of-type').text
```

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<span class="sim-posted">
        
            <span class="jobs-status covid-icon clearfix">
                <i class="covid-home-icon"></i>Work from Home 
            </span>
            <span>Posted few days ago</span>
            
    </span>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

soup.select_one('span.sim-posted span:last-of-type').text
```

#### Output

```
Posted few days ago
```

#### Alternativ

You can also go with `:-soup-contains` a css pseudo class selector to target a node's text. **Needs SoupSieve integration was added in Beautiful Soup 4.7.0.**

```
soup.select_one('span.sim-posted span:-soup-contains("Posted")').text
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will find another span without class inside the span that you reached

```
date_published=job.find('span',class_='sim-posted').find("span", {"class": False}).text
```

Answer (score 0):

To scrape the last *SPAN* tag with text as *Posted few days ago* using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you can use either of the either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *css* with `last-child`:

  ```
  span.sim-posted span:last-child
  ```
- Using *css* with `last-of-type`:

  ```
  span.sim-posted span:last-of-type
  ```
- Using *css* with `nth-child()`:

  ```
  span.sim-posted span:nth-child(2)
  ```
- Using *css* with `nth-of-type()`:

  ```
  span.sim-posted span:nth-of-type(2)
  ```